# Error logging out from Cognito in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, amazon-cognito

I'm struggling with the ASP.NET Core MVC app and the integration to Cognito.

I have managed to get the sign-in functionality working but am now struggling with the sign-out functionality.

I am basing this on the AWS code at https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/02696107-09ac-4313-a6cb-3798048b07d7/en-US/9-how-to-authenticate-users-in-my-application and the example code it supplies.

This has the signout code as the following:

```
    public IActionResult SignOut()
    {
        var callbackUrl = Url.Page("/", pageHandler: null, values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
        return SignOut(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        );
    }
```

After tweaking for my app, this ends up as:

```
    public IActionResult SignOut()
    {
        var baseUri = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}";
 
        //var callbackUrl = Url.Page("/", pageHandler: null, values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);

        return SignOut(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = baseUri },
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        );
    }
```

When I run the app and attempt to sign-out, the sign-out seems to function correctly (in that the cookies are removed). However, the Cognito redirect fails with the following:

[image]

When debugging the code it can be seen that the redirect URI is set to "https://localhost:7085"

Within AWS the App Client is defined as follows (i.e. the same logout URL) - so both values are the same.

[image]

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

After we invoke the *logout* endpoint, it will navigate the user, either to the location specified in the `logout_uri` param OR to the `redirect_uri` param. (Please refer the [docuemtnation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html))

According to the error message ("redirect_mismatch"), this looks like it is trying to use `redirect_uri`. Which means it is trying to send user back to the login page, after successfully logged out.

Please check the Network requests. And I believe this error must be occurring during that login redirect. In such a case, that `redirect_uri` needs to be specified in `Allowed callback URLs` of your app client.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. The redirect URI is definitely set to https://localhost:7085. I have added this URI to both the "Allowed Callback URLs" and "Allowed SIgn-Out URLs" on the App Client settings. 

Unfortunately, this has not made any difference.